# How to overcome 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'excelwriter' in pandas for Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I have refined an existing `xlsx` file and want to create three new files based on the content. Successful in getting three new outputs, but not able to write it to new `xlsx` files.

I tried installing `excelwriter` but that didn't fixed my problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

xl_file = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\python_codes\\myfile.xlsx')

dfs = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx', sheetname="Sheet1")
test = dfs.drop_duplicates(subset='DetectionId', keep='first', inplace=False)

dfs2 = test[test['list_set_id'] == 1]
print(dfs2)

writer = dfs2.ExcelWriter('newfile.xlxs', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

I want to write new `xlsx` file with the filtered content from the existing file.

Comment: As you can see, `df` is an pandas.DataFrame object.. right? And the dataframe doesn't have `ExcelWriter`. So, you can use `dfs2.to_excel()` instead

Comment: As @DeepSpace has suggested, please take a look again at your code and replace  `writer = dfs2.ExcelWriter...` with `writer = pd.ExcelWriter`. You can look at the [xlsxwriter docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) for more information

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter) belongs to the `pandas` module, not to a `DataFrame` instance.

`writer = dfs2.ExcelWriter` should be `writer = pd.ExcelWriter`